# How does this example violate LSP, which then causes violation of OCP?

Tags: solid-principles, design-principles, liskov-substitution-principle, open-closed-principle

From [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://flylib.com/books/en/4.444.1.64/1/) by Robert Martin,

> Listing   10-1.   A   violation   of  LSP causing a    violation  of  OCP
>
> ```
> struct    Point   {double x,  y;}
> public    enum    ShapeType   {square,    circle};
> public    class   Shape
> {
>       private ShapeType   type;
>       public  Shape(ShapeType t){type =   t;}
>       public  static  void    DrawShape(Shape s)
>       {
>               if(s.type   ==  ShapeType.square)
>                       (s  as  Square).Draw();
>               else    if(s.type   ==  ShapeType.circle)
>                       (s  as  Circle).Draw();
>       }
> }
> public    class   Circle  :   Shape
> {
>       private Point   center;
>       private double  radius;
>       public  Circle()    :   base(ShapeType.circle)  {}
>       public  void    Draw()  {/* draws   the circle  */}
> }
> public    class   Square  :   Shape
> {
>       private Point   topLeft;
>       private double  side;
>       public  Square()    :   base(ShapeType.square)  {}
>       public  void    Draw()  {/* draws   the square  */}
> }
> ```
>
> `DrawShape()` violates    OCP.    It
>   must    know    about   every   possible    derivative  of  the  Shape  class,
>   and it  must    be  changed whenever    new derivatives of   Shape  are
>   created.
>
> The   fact    that     `Square`   and  `Circle`   cannot  be  substituted for `Shape`     is  a
>   violation   of  LSP.    This    violation   forced  the violation   of  OCP by
>   DrawShape . Thus,   a   violation   of  LSP is  a   latent  violation   of  OCP.

How does it violate LSP?
(In particular, why can `Square`    and  `Circle`   not be  substituted for  `Shape`?)

How does violation of LSP cause violation of OCP? (I can  see it directly violates OCP, but I can't understand how violation of LSP causes violation of OCP.)

Answer (score 4):

This is not an obvious or typical LSP violation, and one could argue that it isn't an LSP violation at all, but here's my interpretation:

The expectation is that a `Shape` is described by its `type` field. When `DrawShape` receives a `Shape` object, one of a few things can happen. Depending on the value of the `type` field, it could try to cast the object to a `Square` and call its `Draw` function, or try to cast it to a `Circle` to the same end. However, this is not guaranteed to work as expected for an arbitrary `Shape`. Specifically, it will only work if the object's dynamic type actually matches the semantic implication of it's `type` field. If the `type` field does not match its dynamic type, an exception will occur when trying to perform the dynamic cast. This is the behavior of `DrawShape` given a `Shape` object.

However, given a `Square` or `Circle`, there is a different expectation. Specifically, the function is expected to always execute one path or another without an exception, since the semantic implication of the `type` field will always match the object's dynamic type.

In other words, you could consider the `DrawShape` function to have four interesting paths of execution for a `Shape` object: an exception occuring at the dynamic `Circle` cast, an exception occuring at the dynamic `Square` cast, or a successful execution of either the `Square` or `Circle` draw functions.

When a child is substituted, the first two paths mentioned are no longer possible, and for a given child, only one path is possible.

Alternatively, it could be argued that there is no LSP violation; the function still "acts" in the same way for a child substitution as it would for a parent. `Squares` and `Circles` simply have an extra implication, being that the `type` field will definitely match the dynamic type of the object, restricting the execution results of the function at runtime. While it could be thought of as changing the function expectations, it could also simply be thought of as imposing a pre-condition.

**Edit**

I suppose I forgot to answer part of the question: The reason this supposed LSP violation "causes" an OCP violation is because the function logic which causes the behavior to be different for `Shapes` versus `Squares` and `Circles`, being the dynamic casting to the children, is the very same logic which forces the `Shape` class to depend on its children. Thus, by violating the LSP using conditional logic about the subclasses, it in turn violates the OCP.

I don't know if I myself would really call this particular case a situation of "causation" so much as simple event intersection, but perhaps this was the author's intention.

Comment: When you say "If the type field does not match its dynamic type", why would that happen?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what I meant. In the given example, that would *never* happen given a well-defined program. Well, if a *new* derived class was introduced with `type == ShapeType.square`, that would break the `Shape` class. But this has nothing to do with `Square` or `Circle` and whether or not they can be substituted for `Shape`. So in my opinion, there is a clear OCP violation and a strong potential for an LSP violation by introducing a new derived class with a bad `type` value, but I disagree that there's *actually* any LSP violation in the given example as it stands.